# What is the data type of column type -3 in tcResultSet oim?

Tags: java, api, oim

While printing processtask information I am getting some non human readable values for column `Process Instance.Task Details.Row Version`

When I checked the column type via API `tcResultSet.getColumnType("Process Instance.Task Details.Row Version")`it is returning column type as `-3`.

can you help me read the version? I tried using long, float but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column type of this is `ByteArray`. You can read the value by using `tcResultSet.getByteArrayValue`

```
byte[] bArray = trs.getByteArrayValue(columnArray[j]);
//  value = new String(bArray);   // returns some char non readable

for (int k = 0; k < bArray.length; k++) 
{
    value += bArray[k];
}

System.out.print(value + ";");
```